# $f \in C^1$ and $ \forall x \in [-1;1]$ we have $|f'(x)|<1$.Prove $\exists C \in [0;1[$ s.t. $\forall x,y \in [-1;1]$ we have $|f(x)-f(y)|<C|x-y|$.

Tags: calculus, general-topology, solution-verification

**Question:**
Let a function $f$ with the following properties $f:[-1;1] \rightarrow [-1;1]$ and $f \in C^1$ and $ \forall x \in [-1;1]$ we have $|f'(x)|<1$. Prove that $\exists C \in [0;1[$ s.t. $\forall x,y \in [-1;1]$ we have $|f(x)-f(y)|<C|x-y|$.
Rem: $x \neq y$ (not in the original statement).

**My answer:** *Wrong answer see Ryszard Szwarc comment see my new answer below*
By absurd: let suppose that $\exists x,y \in [-1;1]$ s.t. there is none $0 \leq C < 1$ s.t. $|f(x)-f(y)|<C|x-y|$. In other words it means that $\forall 0 \leq C < 1$ we have $|f(x)-f(y)| \geq C|x-y|$ for this two specific point $x$ and $y$.
This leads to the following inequality: $\forall 0 \leq C < 1 \Rightarrow \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}\geq C \Rightarrow \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}\geq 1$.
Now by [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) we have that: $\exists z \in ]x;y[$ s.t. $|f'(z)|=\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|} \Rightarrow |f'(z)| \geq 1$ according to what we wrote just above, contradiction. Q.E.D.

Is this correct?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just let $C = \max_x |f'(x)| < 1$ and apply the mean value theorem directly.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. If you apply the proof by contradiction, then   for any $C<$ there exist $x,y$. Which means $x$ and $y$ depend on $C.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thk you for your comment. I didn't understand well your comment. Can you explain it more or/and can you write an answer

Comment: @copper.hat I ve written an answer based on your comment can you check if it is correct?Thk.

Comment: The statement of the problem has a small issue, either you need $x \ne y$ or $\le$. If $x =y$ the statement cannot be true.

Comment: @copper.hat thk for your answer. If I understood you well I don't think that there is a problem on the statement $\leq$. Can you read my prove in the answer (for $<$) and told me if it is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Based on copper.hat comment.*
Let prove that such a $C$ exists by construction.
Choose $C'= Max_{-1 \leq x \leq 1} |f'(x)|<1$ (inferior to $1$ by hypothesis).
Now by the mean value theorem $\forall x,y \in [-1;1] \Rightarrow \exists z \in ]x;y[$  s.t.  $|f'(z)|=\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|} \leq C' \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|\leq C'|x-y|$.
Now we define: $C= C'+\frac{|1-C'|}{2}>C' \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|\leq C'|x-y|<C |x-y|$. Note that by construction $C<1$ hence Q.E.D.
Rem: $x \neq y$

Is this correct now? (Edit: yes it is according to RyszardSzwarc )

Comment: It's fine now. Just add $x\neq y.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc thank a lot

Comment: The specification of $C$ is unnecessarily complicated. Just set $C=C'+1$

Comment: @copper.hat I am not sure about that as $C$ has to be stly smaller than $1$ . That why I defined in that way.

Comment: My apologies, I missed that part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

In order to contradict the conclusion we get: for any $0\le C<1$ there exist $x,y\in [-1,1]$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|>C|x-y|.$
What you did was:  there exist $x,y\in [-1,1]$ such that for all $0\le C< 1$ there holds  $|f(x)-f(y)|>C|x-y|.$ It is not a correct negation of the conclusion. The order of quantifiers is wrong.

Comment: Thk for your comment I understand better now. I ve written a different answer base on @copper.hat comment can you tell me if it is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x,y\in [-1,1]$. From MVT there is a $a\in (-1,1)$ such that $|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}|=|f'(a)|<1$, which means that all the absolute secants' slopes of function 's graph $Γ_f$ are bounded $(1)$.

Consider the set $S$ to be the set of all these slopes. From Completeness Axiom $S$ has a supremum. We suppose that $\sup S=1$ (obviously $\sup S\geq 0$). From characterization of supremum for all $n\in \Bbb N$ there are $x_n, y_n \in [0,1]$ such that $1-\frac 1n <\frac {f(x_n)-f(y_n)}{x_n-y_n}\leq 1$. From MVT in $[x_n,y_n]$ there is a $ξ_n \in (x_n, y_n)$ such that $1-\frac 1n <f'(ξ_n)\leq 1$.

Sequences $x_n, y_n$ are bounded, so they have convergent subsequences, let $x_{κ_n}, y_{λ_n}$ with limits $x,y$.

If $x=y:=u$, then there is a $ξ_{μ_n}\in (x_{κ_n}, y_{λ_n})$ such that $1-\frac 1n <f'(ξ_{μ_n})\leq 1$. However $f'(ξ_{μ_n})\to f'(u)$, because $f\in C^1$. Hence $f'(u)=1$, which is a contradiction with $f'(x)<1$ in $[-1,1].

If $x\neq y$, then $1-\frac 1n <\frac {f(x_{κ_n})-f(y_{λ_n})}{x_{κ_n}-y_{λ_n}}\leq 1$, so $\frac {f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}=1$, a contradiction with $(1)$.

Consequently $\sup S<1$, so there is a $C\in (0,1)$ such that $|\frac {f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}|<C$ in $[-1,1]$.

Comment: It seems you are trying to avoid the  continuity of $f'.$ However it  may happen that $x_{k_n}-y_{k_n}$ tends to $0,$ i.e. $x=y.$ In such case the existence of the limit requires the continuity of $f'.$

Comment: Of course you are right. I didn' t avoid it; I didn' t type the prime by accident. I fix it immediately. Thank you for your note.

Comment: I added an analytic explanation for the last part.